# Prohibited from deleting or disabling Android app

Tags: android

I'm a beginner Android developer who's interested in the possibility of making my app non-removable and non-disableable via GUI Options Manager. I have figured out that system applications (which are non removable using gui) are located at /system/app, but they can be disabled except for some apps (Launcher, sim tools, etc). I'm wonder, how I could make the same behavior with my app?

This is not malware, but a build-in app in my own device, so I can have full access (sdk/ndk), if it helps somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Read about AlarmManager, it used for gmail, launchers, after application dies, this alarmmanager initialize our app.

other way? root access! =/